# Difference between consecutive maxima and minima in a .csv dataset

Tags: excel, csv

I have a dataset which represents tracking data of a mouse's paw moving up and down in the y-axis as it reaches up for and pulls down on a piece of string. 
The output of the data is a list of y-coordinates corresponding to a fraction of a second. For example:

```
1   333.9929833
2   345.4504726
3   355.7046572
4   367.6136684
5   379.7906121
6   390.5470788
7   397.9017118
8   403.677123
9   412.1550843
10  416.516814
11  419.8205706
12  423.7994881
13  429.4874275
14  419.2652898
15  360.1626136
16  298.8212249
17  264.3647809
18  265.0078862
19  268.1828407
20  283.101321
21  294.8219163
22  308.4875135
```

In this series, there is a max value of 429... and a minimum of 264... - however, as you can see from an example image:

[image]

(excuse the gaps), there are multiple consecutive wave-like maxima and minima.

The goal is to find the difference between each maxima and consecutive minima, and each minima and consecutive maxima (i.e. max1-min1, min2-max1, max2-min2...). Ideally, this would also provide the timepoints of each max and min (e.g. 13 and 17 for the provided dataset) - there is a column with integer labels (1, 2, 3...) corresponding to each coordinate. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, I have done this manually (record the value for each max or min, then find the difference between consecutive ones) and by using the =MAX and =MIN function in excel, with the series of values manually determined and subtracting the difference. Both require me to manually look through the data, which is slower than I would like it to be.